# Android Firebase automatic login after registration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build this app with firebase and I wanted when as soon as the user is registered they will be automatically login and be redirected to another page where it ask them to choose their interest and from there they will be redirected to their news feed. But the problem I'm noticing is that firebase only login the user when the app is restarted and that's not what I want. Can someone please guide me with this here's my code below

//Register Activity

```
    uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signupemail);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signuppassword);

    signinbutton=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.have_an_account_button);
    signupbutton=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.signupbutton1);

    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    signupbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String txt_uname=uname.getText().toString();
            final String txt_email=email.getText().toString();
            final String txt_password=password.getText().toString();

            if(txt_uname.isEmpty() ){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Name required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }





            if(txt_email.isEmpty()){

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Email required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            if(txt_password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }



            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txt_email,txt_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                       Users information=new Users(

                                txt_uname,
                                txt_email,
                               "",
                               "",
                               "",
                               "",
                               ""

                        );

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(information).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                if(firebaseAuth != null){

                                    Intent inty=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,CategoryActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(inty);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){

                      email.setError("Email exist");
                      email.requestFocus();

                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you know if user is logged in or not? It should be logged in after first OnCompleteListener is executed. 
Btw, 'if(firebaseAuth != null){'  is always true in your example. To check if user is logged in or not you should call `getCurrentUser()`. Look at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()

Comment: @Mladen I notice that after the user registers and I close the app and reopen it I notice that the user is logged in and I put something where it says if the user is logged in then send them to their profile page and it shows their information that's how I know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t help you with this level of info. This code seems to work, if you fix mix’n’matching of `firebaseAuth` and Firebase’s `User` object (from `getCurrentUser()` method ). Or you are mistakenly checking some database entry as info if a ‘User’ is logged in.
Try either debugging or printing a bit more info. I’m pretty sure you are getting logged in after executing `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. 
Please take a look at linked answers as well.

Comment: @Mladen actually you already helped me. I had to use getCurrentUser() and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that, pleasure ;)